# Authorization Token is not being received by Django server from ios - React native

Tags: ios, django, rest, react-native

When I do a request using Fetch (in ios) from a react native app with a Django backend, the header Authorization Token is not being received, but the others headers are.

I try using nc -l 8090 just to check out if the app was correctly sending the header and it was there. Also, this just happens in the ios version, the android one works just fine.

At checking the Django backend, the Authorization Token is not being received ( I printed what i got in the authentication.py file )

I put the fetch code here:

```
let response = fetch('http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8000/' + 'users', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'x-app-key': xxxxxxxxxx,
        'Authorization': 'Token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
      }
    }).then((response) => {...}
```

The error message that im getting in the response is "403 django standar not valid authentication".

I'm not using OAuth2. Any other information that could provide, please let me know and thank you for any help.

Something weird that I just noticed is that when I use the nc cmd (lc -l 8000), at the port 8000, it has the same behavior. The authorization token is not being received.

Comment: Did you fix this error?

Answer (score 5):

I solved my problem added a slash at the end of the URL.

```js
let response = fetch('http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8000/' + 'users/', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'x-app-key': xxxxxxxxxx,
        'Authorization': 'Token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
      }
    }).then((response) => {...}
```

Comment: Interestingly, without the slash at the end, it works on Android only. With the slash, it works on iOS as well. That makes me believe Android adds the slash for you.

Comment: I had the same problem, is working with Android and Flutter, but not iOS native in Swift until I add the slash `/` at the end of the URL as suggested

Comment: i went so much in [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#apache-mod_wsgi-specific-configuration) direction :/ was struggling with this much, thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

I had a variation of this issue with a backend using the laravel framework. I finally resolved it by using the following in the .htaccess file of the public folder.

```
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Combined with one other important factor in my case, losing the trailing slash from the url in the fetch.

Hope this helps, either way. Good luck.